# Mirror Front-facing camera in browser

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

How can I distinguish between the front and environment facing cameras in browsers ? I am trying to mirror the user facing camera but keep the environment facing camera as is.

I've tried a few ideas:

- Using `getusermedia({video: {facingMode : {exact: "user"}}})` but it seems like facingMode property is empty in most browsers)
- Use the Camera label to look for "front". This might work for Tablets or laptops with two cameras but laptops with only front facing cameras will not have it.